# Oracle to Snowflake data sourcing

Tags: oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working to create Data Lake in snowflake and source is Oracle DB.
What are the best way to sourced data from Oracle DB to Snowflake?

Comment: HI, is your data movement one time or is it continuous ? Do you want to do a CDC on your source ?  One method that we use at our work place is to use Attunity to move the data. If you are using any ETL tool than you can use that to copy the data.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake has a number of ways to load data but always include a stage area.

From on-prem the data would need to be PUT into a stage, either straight into a stage on the cloud like S3 buckets for AWS or Azure Blob Store on ... Azure! I forgot what the GCP option is called. This can be registered as an external stage.

You can also PUT the file into Snowflake's internal stage, that way the data is encrypted right away without you needing to configure that.

After the stage the data is COPYied into a table, now the options for doing the above vary depending on what you want to do.

- use an ETL/ELT tool, this will automate some of the above and give you lineage
- use Snowpipe, this is for smaller workloads that load more frequently

How the data gets to the stage you need to work out, every customer is different. It could be one of the above or even using Kafka, there's a bit of work for you involved which would also depend on how you will get the data there for Snowflake.